# How to replace nested loops with LINQ - in a clean, manageable manner

Tags: c#, linq, loops

Codewise, what it the cleanest way to do this using linq? Below, I have a crude example where I want to find a matching class instance based on name.

```
class item
{
   string name {get;set;}
   int identifier {get;set;}
}

void DoSomething()
{
  List<item> List1 = GetSampleItems();
  List<item> List2 = GetOtherSampleItems();

  for(int a=0;a<List1.count;a++)
  {
     for(int b=0;b<List2.count;b++)
     {
         if(List1[a].identifier == List2[b].identifier)
         { 
            List1[a].name = List2[b].name;
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: LINQ isn't magic. Just because you don't write the nested loops, it doesn't mean LINQ wont use them. And what is your definition of "better"?

Comment: I guess the size of both lists is guaranteed to be the same? Because if not, there's going to be a problem.

Comment: Sorry, by better I meant either more efficient from a resource perspective OR just cleaner, easier to maintain code.

Comment: Matt, what makes you say they'd have to be the same size?  List 2 could simply be empty, no matches would be found, and nothing in list 1 would change after the loops have run.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg: Well pick one. If you want better performance then you should include some benchmarks that highlight the issues. If you want to know the LINQ version then reword your question to be specifically about converting it to LINQ. It's not up to us to decide what kind of question you are asking.

Comment: @musefan I understand I was a little vague - I wasn't sure what I was looking for. I thought maybe linq, but for all I knew, the consensus could have been that the approach I took was acceptable. I wasn't sure I was doing anything wrong, I just wanted to know how other people might have done it, if that makes sense. My original title was edited by someone else to make the question specifically ask for linq.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg: It does make sense, but SO doesn't generally accept questions asking or people opinions on a preferred method. I am very surprised this question has received so many upvotes to be honest.

Comment: @musefan I edited the question and title, to specifically ask for a linq replacement. Linq is what I was expecting, and I received excellent answers using it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*, so you'll still need to loop through the results to make the changes, but you can `join` to match up the two lists like so:

```
var query = from l1 in List1
            join l2 in List2
                on l1.identifier equals l2.identifier 
            select new {l1, l2};
```

Now loop through the query to update the `l1` items:

```
foreach(var item in query)
    item.l1.name = item.l2.name;
```

As a side note, there's nothing *wrong* with the way you're doing it (other than you could break out of the inner loop if a match is found).  If you understand how it works and the performance is acceptable, there's no compelling reason to change it.

Comment: The OP asked for a better way... I prefer the original nested loops than this. Does that justify a downvote? (not really sure)

Comment: There *is* something wrong with what he's doing in his non-LINQ solution though; something that you fixed in your LINQ solution (apparently without realizing it).  He was comparing each item to each other item, which is an O(n * m) operation; he can avoid those comparisons though the use of a hash based lookup, achieving O(n + m) performance.  That's what LINQ's Join does.  He could alter his non-LINQ solution to use such a structure as well to provide that rather dramatic improvement.

Comment: @musefan See my comment; nested loops results in *dramatically* worse performance; not that you couldn't get the performance improvement without using LINQ.

Comment: @musefan can you point me to an existing question or article I might look at for a good improvement without LINQ?

Comment: @Servy: Indeed, I will always avoid nested loops when possible for performance reasons. I just prefer looking at the other code. To be honest, I am not even sure why the OP is doing this. It looks a bit like some sort of "copy" function, which I would look to be doing a different way completely if that was the requirement

Comment: @Servy I mean "wrong" in the sense of "wrong results" or "wrong logic".  Certainly it's doing more work than necessary (which can also be fixed without linq as I mentioned) but it's not "wrong"; it's just not "optimal".

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg just `break` out of the inner loop when a match is found.  That will reduce the number of iterations.  `join` offers some additional performance benefits, but with small lists the difference may not be noticeable.

Comment: @DStanley Breaking out of the loop still leaves it a O(N * M) algorithm, rather than an O(N + M) algorithm.  That's a *very* significant difference as far as algorithms go.  Yes, if the data sets are all small then it's entirely irrelevant if the algorithm is completely the wrong algorithm for the job and is going to perform a large portion of unnecessary work, and yet the question was specifically mentioning improving the performance of the algorithm, so one can assume it *is* relevant.

Comment: @musefan I apologize for the example being rather useless. My original code involved two checked list boxes and looping through each to find items that were checkmarked in both boxes. I tried to boil the code down to something very generic.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg: You should have stuck with the 2 checkedlists in your question as there may be other factors to consider when improving performance. Such as casting, and using the `CheckedItems` collection.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var query = from l1 in List1
            join l2 in List2 on l1.identifier equals l2.identifier
            select new 
            {
                l1values = l1,
                l2Name = l2.name
            };

foreach(var item in query)
    item.l1Values.name = item.l2Name;
```

Comment: If I'm correct, this will throw NREs on items in l1 that don't have a match in l2.  Better to just select l2 and then do a Where l2 is not null.

Comment: well this answer closely matche the answer given by @D Stanley, although i was beaten to the punch!

Comment: @Will no, if there's not a match in the second list the first list item will not be in the result set.

Answer (score 4):

A better way is using a [`Dictionary<TK,TV>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dictionary<int,item> l2dic = List2.ToDictionary(x => x.identifier);
item itm;
List1.ForEach(x => {
    if(l2dic.TryGetValue(x.identifier,out itm)) {
        x.name = itm.name;
    }
});
```

Or as @Rawling says, use a `foreach` loop instead:

```
Dictionary<int,item> l2dic = List2.ToDictionary(x => x.identifier);
item itm;
foreach(item x in List1) {
    if(l2dic.TryGetValue(x.identifier,out itm)) {
        x.name = itm.name;
    }
}
```

[**Ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/vkqghS) (with slight modifications to your `item` class).

This runs on average in linear time whereas your approach runs in quadratic time.

The **assumption** is however that the identifiers are unique: no two elements in the same list can have the same identifier.

A concluding note is that variables in general start with a lowercase character so `list1` and `list2` whereas classes and properties start with a capital one (this `Item`, `Identifier` and `Name`).

Comment: You *could* even use a regular `foreach` loop rather than the abomination that is `List.ForEach`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was harsh and it's gone :)

Comment: @Rawling: well I agree it is perhaps more elegant to use a `foreach` loop, but it's not that bad. Although I agree *Linq* developers probably would have better not introduced it... ;)

Comment: @CommuSoft: I think including both variations of the foreach is polluting the answer. Just keep it simple and pick one or the other